# Safely passing email and password to REST API

Tags: android, rest, authentication, android-intent

How can I safely pass a user's email and password from an Android app over to my web server's REST API for authentication?

Would it be safe to create a POST request to a route, like:

```
http://www.website.com/user/login
```

Are there other ways to do it? Safer ways? What safety concerns should I know about?

Comment: For a start you'd want to use HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the password should only be a "login action". Obviously, this login call must be done via https in order to be safer.

The problem is that a mechanism based on a password attached to every request is not safe enough.

***The two main methods***

**Via cookies**: You interchange a cookie between client and server. You obviously have to handle the authentiacion in server to validate the request. Classic way.

**Via tokens** (OAuth2 way): You interchange a refresh token (long duration, maybe days, months... it's customizable) and an authentication token (temporary and refreshed with the refresh token). You have also to handle this on server (to set scopes and times,validation etc.).

I'm always thinking in a password for an user/session. Don't store "masters passwords" for services in your APK!! Never!! **APK has no secrets**, they can be easily decompiled.

I hope this would help you ;)